# How to pass php array to javascript in form of json?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, google-maps

I have this php array

```
Array
(
    [66] => Array
        (
            [lat] => 19.0632
            [long] => 72.8446
        )

)
Array
(
    [296] => Array
        (
            [lat] => 29.252192
            [long] => 76.4519704
        )

)
Array
(
    [631] => Array
        (
            [lat] => 1000
            [long] => 2500
        )

)
Array
(
    [632] => Array
        (
            [lat] => 1000
            [long] => 30000
        )

)
```

and following js code to show map

```
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(19.0632,72.8446);
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
  var mapOptions = {center: myCenter, zoom: 14};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:myCenter});
  marker.setMap(map);
```

What i want? I want to display all the location from PHP array on map using above JS code.

How can I pass all this latitude and longitude to the variable 'myCenter' using foreach?

Is there any way how to pass PHP array to js?

Comment: You can store PHP array into javascript and use for loop to create an object of LatLng.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code.

```
$products = array(
    array('choc_cake', 'Chocolate Cake', 15),
    array('carrot_cake', 'Carrot Cake', 12),
    array('cheese_cake', 'Cheese Cake', 20),
    array('banana_bread', 'Banana Bread', 14)
);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var products = <?php echo json_encode( $products ) ?>;
alert( products[0][1] ); // Chocolate Cake
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass like this

```
<script>
var result = <?php echo json_encode($result) ?>;
$.each(result, function (i, elem) {
    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(elem.lat,elem.long);
  // do your stuff
});
<script>
```

Note : $result is your array that you define